# Firestore order by and limit not working in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following firestore setup:

```
-Root
 - Queue
   - item1
      - time : 20
   - item2
     - time : 1
   - 2000 more items, with a random time value
```

What i want is to show 40 items, with smallest time first so i do the following in kotlin:

```
val ref = firestore.collection("Queue")
orderBy?.let{
  ref.orderBy(it)
}
limit?.let{
  ref.limit(it)
}
return ref.get().get().toObjects(Queue::class.java)
```

It actually completly ignore my order by and limit statements. and is returning all items in the Queue collection, what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query

says that the orderBy and limit methods return a new query object, so maybe you should try

```
val ref = firestore.collection("Queue").orderBy("time").limit(40)
```

As per the update to your question, you could create a function that returns the query you want based on whether or not the orderBy and limit query modifiers are present. You would have to make that query object a var in order to make it mutable.